# provide full author name lists in reference section with latex

Tags: bibliographies

I'm try to publish my research with journal,
that send me this note :

In the reference section, please provide the full author name lists for any references with 'et al.'

how can I do this?
please help me :(

Comment: Well, you give us no information about your document, or how you generated your reference list. So how are we suppose to help?

Comment: Also *please* tag your question correctly. You added the `overleaf` tag; is your question specific to Overleaf?

Comment: @bonk - I changed the posting's tag to `bibliographies`.

Comment: @daleif it's peerj template, I don't know how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you created your paper's bibliography via software (such as BibTeX or biblatex/biber) -- a big if at this point! -- you need to go into the bib file(s) and backfill the missing information.

Presumably, the `author` field of some entry looks like this:

```
author={Jane Jones and others}
```

If that's the case, it's up to *you* to find out who the other authors of this piece may be. As a result of your research, you may decide that you should change this `author` field to, say,

```
author={Jane Jones and Michelle Miller and Stefanie Smith and Yvonne Yaremski}
```

Be sure to obtain the complete author lists and, for each author, the complete set of given names.

Comment: I try this solution but not work well. this my list: author={Fergus J. Couch, Hermela Shimelis, Chunling Hu, Steven N. Hart, Eric C. Polley, Jie Na, Emily Hallberg, Raymond Moore, Abigail Thomas, Jenna Lilyquist, Bingjian Feng, Rachel McFarland, Tina Pesaran, Robert Huether, Holly LaDuca, Elizabeth C. Chao, David E. Goldgar, Jill S. Dolinsky} and it's appear like this Fergus J. Couch, Hermela Shimelis, C. H. S. N. H. E. C. P. J. N. E. H. R. M. A. T. J. L. B. F. R. M. T.359
P. R. H. H. L. E. C. C. D. E. G. J. S. D. (2017). Associations between cancer ....

Comment: @ARWAABDULKADERBASHANFAR You need to use `and` between the names. And please update your question so people can stop guessing.

Comment: @ARWAABDULKADERBASHANFAR - Please *look closely* at my suggested answer and take note of the `and` key word that acts as a separator between the names. Don't ignore it.

Comment: thank you , it's work now

Answer (score 1):

I will make some assumptions here. To address the journal's request, you may need to modify or check some stuff.

1. If you have a BibTeX file (`.bib`) look for any entry that has "`an others`" in the author field. If you do, put the complete list of authors.
2. Make sure the names in the `author` field are separated by "`and`" (for example, `author = {John Doe and Jane Smith}`).
3. Make sure you are using the right bibliography style (of the journal). The `.bst` file may determine the maximum number of authors that are showing, see next item. Look for the command `\bibliographystyle{}`, it should be near the end of your main `.tex` document.
4. Make sure whichever package you are using to deal with the bibliography is not limiting the number of authors (for example, options like `maxcitenames=3`).
5. When using Overleaf, make sure you do not have any previous `output.bbl` file in your roll of files.
6. After making changes to your `.bib` file, recompile your LaTeX document. Moreover, when in Overleaf try "Recompile from scratch".

These are some ideas to solve your issue.